# Loading Json to one class and send them to different classes

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-fragments

Just bear with me, new to development, I am trying to load a json file in a Fragment class whose xml has view pager, tablayout. My target is to load all data in One class then after parsing in same class, through bundle or other, want to send those data to different tabs. I tried with my approach and if there is any other way to do this,then you could post it here. Deeply Appreciated.
You could give a look through the code.

nd_home_main_VP.java(Loads all json here)

```
public class nd_home_main_VP extends Fragment {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private View view=null;

private FrameLayout frameLayout2;
private static final String boom="http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";

private Fragment fragment;

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
String b;

Bundle bundle2=new Bundle();
String b2;

private FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

public nd_home_main_VP() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.nd_menu, container, false);

    frameLayout2=(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fl_id);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_home_id);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_1_home_id);

    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, boom, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response_jsonArray) {
            Log.d("YES",response_jsonArray.toString());

            for(int i=0;i<response_jsonArray.length();i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=response_jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    b=jsonObject.getString("rating");
                    bundle.putString("message", b);
                    Log.d("b",bundle.toString());

                    b2=jsonObject.getString("releaseYear");
                    bundle2.putString("message2",b);
                    Log.d("b2",bundle2.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

    return view;
}
public void doTransaction(){
    fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_id,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                fragment=new OneFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                doTransaction();
                return fragment;
            case 2:

                fragment=new TwoFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle2);
                doTransaction();
                return fragment;

            default:
        }
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
   }
}
```

In xml file, I got FrameLayout, TabLayout and a ViewPager

This is the error here
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:`                                                                             Can't change container ID of fragment
`OneFragment{32fbf30a id=0x7f0d007c android:switcher:2131558526:1}: was 2131558524 now 2131558526`

I would like to know what would be best way to approach this and Now you could check the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove

```
       switch (position){
            case 1:
                fragment=new OneFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                doTransaction();
                return fragment;
            case 2:

                fragment=new TwoFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle2);
                doTransaction();
                return fragment;

            default:
        }
```

you created the two fragments outside the adapter, so no need to recreate them inside the `getItem` callback. Indeed, no need to call `doTransaction` because the `viewPagerAdapter` will handle it.

Comment: If you remove this,the how would you send data across other tab when viewpager is swiped

Comment: You have to pass data when you create the fragment instance: take a look at this: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: okay so when json gets loaded to one class,the should I need to send this to other layouts(tab) as you instructed above, and swiping of viwpager ?

Comment: Yes,Cyborg I would have asked the same.I am loading all this to MainACtivity class where I have got two tab class.ANd I want to send specific data to each ctab class from Main

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are applying both approach adding fragment and setting adapter remove one of them and for better use.

Please follow [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) example to add fragment with view pager.